# Animations on Maple

Tags: maple

I'm working on some textbook problems for Maple, and I encountered the following problem:

> Create an animation to illustrate the differences between line thicknesses in Maple (you
>   can choose any function to plot). After the thicknesses, illustrate line styles. Note: you
>   will have to create multiple animations and string them together.

I chose $f(x)=x^2$ as my function, and my code is the following:

`with(plots):`

`lt := display(seq(`$`(plot(x^2, x = -3 .. 3, 0 .. 5, thickness = t), 10), t = 0 .. 3), insequence = true)`

`ls := display(seq(`$`(plot(x^2, x = -3 .. 3, 0 .. 5, linestyle = t), 10), t = 0 .. 4), insequence = true)`

`display(lt, ls, insequence = true)`

`tlt := display(seq(`$`(textplot([2, 1, convert(t, string)]), 10), t = 0 .. 3), insequence = true)`

`tls := display(seq(`$`(textplot([2, 1, convert(t, string)]), 10), t = 0 .. 3), insequence = true)`

`> display(display(lt, ls, insequence = true), display(tlt, tls, insequence = true));`

Does anybody have any idea why it isn't working?

P.S. The dollar signs are not supposed to be at that position in my code. For some reason when I copy + pasted my code they appeared on here. The dollar sign appears right after `=t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amongst other things, the values for `t` in your original creation of `ls` are taken from the numeric range `0..4`. But that kind of numeric value will not be a valid linestyle.

Is this the kind of thing you are trying to do? (I've tried to keep to your approach... as it is your assignment.)

```
restart:
with(plots):

lt := seq(display(plot(x^2, x = -3 .. 3, 0 .. 5, thickness = t),
                  textplot([2, 1, convert(t, string)]))$3,
                  t = 1 .. 10):

display(lt, insequence = true);

ls := seq(display(plot(x^2, x = -3 .. 3, 0 .. 5, linestyle = t),
                  textplot([2, 1, convert(t, string)]))$10,
                  t = [dash,dashdot,longdash,solid,spacedash,spacedot]):

display(ls, insequence = true);

display(lt, ls, insequence = true);
```